# Reusing results from a single SELECT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, which is a single query that contains 3 SELECTs in total:

```
SELECT a
FROM tbl
WHERE   b IN ((SELECT a FROM tbl WHERE b = 44))
AND NOT a IN ((SELECT a FROM tbl WHERE b = 44))
```

The query

```
SELECT a FROM table WHERE b = 44
```

is exactly the same, and I'm guessing that the database is running this 2 times, even though it should be faster the second time due to caching etc.

Is there a way in SQL or something specific to MySQL that I can do to reuse 100% of the results from the first one the query is executed?

Or any other ideas on how to speed up this query?

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding sub queries and using joins (which should use indexes and be more efficient).

```
SELECT tbl1.a
FROM tbl tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl tbl2 ON tbl1.b = tbl2.a AND tbl2.b = 44
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl tbl3 ON tbl1.a = tbl3.a AND tbl3.b = 44
WHERE tbl3.a IS NULL
```

Depending on whether you can get multiple matches on the joins then you might need to use DISTINCT after the SELECT.

Comment: Works! It's almost 2x slower than my original one though.. even though both a and b have indexes. Is it the joins that are costing that much?

Comment: The joins should normally be far quicker than using the sub queries. Can you post up your table declares and an EXPLAIN of the query? Do you have an index covering BOTH a and b?

Comment: Sure, created this gist for the explain's - https://gist.github.com/Niklas9/5dd08c4d6b3b7b029365

No, index for a and b separately. @Kickstart

Comment: @Niklas9 - looking at that it suggests that MySQL has processed part of your original query as a JOIN rather than as a sub query. Can you try adding an index that covers both _b_ and _a_ (in that order).

Answer (score 0):

Save first SELECT as temporary table then use it for running second query:

```
SELECT a, b
INTO #temtbl
FROM tbl
WHERE   b IN ((SELECT a FROM tbl WHERE b = 44))
AND NOT a IN ((SELECT a FROM tbl WHERE b = 44))

SELECT a,b FROM #temtbl WHERE b = 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do:

```
SELECT tbl1.a
FROM tbl AS t1
INNER JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.b = t.a AND t2.b = 44
WHERE t1.b <> 44
```